# What is the right way of usig " and ' inside sub-arrays in PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, html, arrays

**Which of the following ways is the right one in using the characters " and ' inside PHP's sub-arrays?**

### #1 Way in debugging PHP code

```
$_POST["login['username']"];
```

### #2 My original way in PHP

```
$_POST['login[username]'];
```

My code is now broken after changing all my variables to arrays.

---

The following is the HTML to which the variables refer.

```
<p>Username:
         <input name="login['username']" type="text" cols="92" />
     </p>

     <p>Email:
         <input name="login['email']" type="text" cols="92" />
     </p>

     <p>Password:
         <input name="login['password']" type="password" cols="92" />
     </p> 

     <input type="submit" value="OK" />
 </form>
```

**Which one is the right way of the following ways in using arrays in HTML.**

### #11

```
<input name="login['password']" type="password" cols="92" />
```

### #22

```
<input name="login[password]" type="password" cols="92" />
```

**I am at the moment using the ways #1 and #11 unsuccessfully?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the correct form in html is what you have for #22 (no quotes).

Secondly, the entire point of doing this is because it will convert it into an array. When this form is posted, an array is created INSIDE of $_POST called login. To access it, try this:

```
echo $_POST['login']['username']; //echos username
echo $_POST['login']['password']; //echos password
```

Here's a quick overview of how the nesting looks:

```
'_POST' =>
    array
      'login' => 
        array
          'username' => string 'myusername' (length=10)
          'password' => string 'mysecretpassword' (length=16)
```

Try doing this to get a good idea of what's going on and get output like above:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

You'll be able to see all the nesting.

Comment: I get this `Array ( [login] => Array ( [email] => )` for this `$_SESSION['login']['email'] = "ntohuh";`? **Do you know why I do not see the value?**

Comment: I opened a new thread based on this answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275916/to-understand-php-sessions-with-sub-arrays-better

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to quote the array keys in HTML, this is correct:

```
<input name="login[password]" type="password" cols="92" />
```

This will create in $_POST a key 'login' whose value is another array having the key 'password', so you can access it like:

```
$_POST['login']['password']
```

Answer (score -2):

just give your variables normal names: `username`, `password` and `email`. you're creating your own problem.